# Change compiler version for a large number of projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, settings, project

I have over 130 projects in Eclipse, some of them are using java compiler 1.5 and some of them are using 1.6. Is there anyway I can change all of them to 1.6 without going through each of them individually? I tried selecting all projects from Project Explorer, but then there is no Property or Build Path available in the menu.

Comment: You could write a script [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/648862/862441) to find/replace `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=<source-version>` to desired value in `<project>\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`

Comment: Eclipse has "project specific settings" and global defaults. If all of your 1.5 projects are using 1.5 because you set them to project specific and picked 1.5, then, no, there's probably not an easy way to change that (barring writing a script or such like srkavin notes). I could be wrong, but I don't know of a way to override it after you've set projects to have specific settings. (And if you haven't, then they will change when you change the global settings.)

Comment: To add on to srkavin's answer you probably also have to changed the installed facet in org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml to <installed facet="java" version="1.6"/>.

Comment: @srkavin - I would suggest you transforming your comment to an answer. I would do exactly the same (small BASH/windows script), so +1 for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

You could write a script [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/648862/862441) to find/replace `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=<source-version>` to desired value in `<project>\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`